# Real-time data streaming from arduino to powerbi

Tags: python, powerbi

Is there a way to fix the problem of real-time data streaming from Arduino to Powerbi?
The powerbi is capable of streaming real-time data with near-zero latency. Does it achievable through any integration of coding language?